# How to color a framebox around an image

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have made two images where one of them is an inset (image B) as shown.

[image]

I would like to know can I color the frame around image B to blue!40 ? 
Can anyone help?

Many thanks!

I have included the frame around image B (by default it is black in colour) using the following tikz/latex commands.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(a){\includegraphics[width=.70\textwidth]{ia.eps}};
\node(b)[inner sep=0pt,left = 1cm of a] {\phantom{\includegraphics[width=.31\textwidth]{ib.eps}}};
\node(c)[draw, blue!40, minimum size=0.05cm, at=(a)]{};
\begin{scope}[thin,blue!40]
\draw(c.north west) -- (b.north east);
\draw(c.south west) -- (b.south east);
\end{scope}
\node [at=(b),inner sep=0pt,left = 1cm of a]{\framebox[1.0\width]{\includegraphics[width=.30\textwidth]{ib.eps}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: To answer your question, use {\color{red}\fbox{\color{blue}B}}.  But so long as you are already using tikz, you don't need \framebox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `\framebox` but `tikz` facilities:

```
\node [draw=blue!40,thick,at=(b),inner sep=2pt,left = 1cm of a]
             {\includegraphics[width=.30\textwidth]{example-image-b}};
```

The `draw=blue!40,thick` option to the node draws the border with the colour specified. You can also use `line width=0.4pt` instead of `thick`. To adjust the separation of border from image, adjust `inner sep` value.

```
\documentclass{Article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(a){\includegraphics[width=.70\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\node(b)[inner sep=0pt,left = 1cm of a] {\phantom{\includegraphics[width=.31\textwidth]{example-image-b}}};
\node(c)[draw, blue!40, minimum size=0.05cm, at=(a)]{};
\begin{scope}[thin,blue!40]
\draw(c.north west) -- (b.north east);
\draw(c.south west) -- (b.south east);
\end{scope}
\node [draw=blue!40,thick,at=(b),inner sep=2pt,left = 1cm of a]{\includegraphics[width=.30\textwidth]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for the sake of it, if you want the hard way, it is `\fcolorbox` which does this job.

```
 \fcolorbox{<border color>}{<fill color>}{content}
```

Sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
  \fcolorbox{blue!40}{white}{\includegraphics[width=.30\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here the default line thickness is `0.4pt` and the separation between image and border is `\fboxsep` (which is `3pt` by default).